# How do I permanently ignore a LinkedIn request if I don't have an account and don't want to create one?

Tags: linkedin

An aquaintance of mine has sent a request to connect via Linked-In to an email address that doesn't correspond to an actual person, but to a group of people of which I am one. I have ignored the request each time the mail pops up, but I keep getting reminders (new emails, every week or so) about the invitation and I find no link in the email to say "no, thank you" - only a link to accept and a link to view his profile.

I do not have a Linked-In account, and I do not wish to create one - certainly not with this email address. Is there any other way to turn off these reminders and ignore the request than to create an account, accept and then remove connection and delete the account?

Comment: I would guess that if someone from the group will accept the invitation the messages will stop.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The problem is that the OP is *receiving* email invitations, not *sending* invititations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to contact LinkedIn in order for them to block your email address from being used.

You can contact them via [their "Submit Your Question" page](https://help.linkedin.com/app/ask/subject/Block%20Email%20Address)

<sub>Reference: [Receiving Invitations when My Account is Closed: Why do I still receive Invitations when my account is closed?](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/64/kw/stop%20invites/)</sub>

Comment: When posting an answer please can you format and title the links properly as @phwd has done to this answer (see the [revisions](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/16626/revisions) to view the changes) It makes answers much easier to read then just having `REF: link` etc. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could create an email filter to move those specific reminders (or even all linked in reminders) to your trash or junk mail folder.

Without having an account with Linked-in it's going to be hard for linked-in to track any information about you, including that you don't want to participate. Unfortunately, as with most social media sites, you've got to opt in to opt out.

If you don't fancy auto-trashing emails, or your email filter can't get specific enough, you could also contact the person who originally sent the request and ask them to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

There's something suspicious about this invitation because according to [LinkedIn](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3882/kw/how%20often%20does%20linkedin%20sendnd%20out%20reminders%20for%20friend%20requests/session/L3RpbWUvMTMwOTI0OTEyOS9zaWQveFBqcmZEeGs%3D):

> LinkedIn automatically sends reminder
>   emails to Invitation recipients who
>   have not yet responded to your
>   Invitation. Our intention behind
>   sending reminders is to jog the
>   receiver's memory in case they
>   overlooked the original message. No
>   more than two reminders are ever sent
>   and once a member archives or replies
>   to the Invitation, reminders are
>   stopped.